# Unable to resolve "idb" from "node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\esm\index.esm2017.js"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expo

i am facing a problem since past days, and not able to solve it
can anyone help me slight to make it work efficiently

Moreover also have degraded firebase to 9.6.11 as per other solutions on similar site.

`````
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ".......................",
  authDomain: ".......................",
  projectId: ".......................",
  storageBucket: ".......................",
  messagingSenderId: ".......................",
  appId: "......................."
};

// Initialize Firebase
let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = firebase.app()
}

const auth = firebase.auth()

export { auth };````
`````

Answer (score 2):

the issue is solved
thanks.
Create a new file `metro.config.js` in the root folder of your project and add the code snippet in it.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

there's an issue open on the metro repo **facebook/metro#535**

builds work fine again for me after adding this to my metro config:

```
resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the most upper one resolve the issue. If you want to know more, follow this official link - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#step-3-configure-metro

Or just paste the code in a new file **metro.config.js** on your root project folder -

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('cjs');
module.exports = defaultConfig;
```